Trigger $: when value is not used directly
I have this code in my svelte component:
$: {
    console.log(dateRange)
    formatDataForChart()
        .then(data => chartData = data);
}

I want to run FormatDataForChart() when dateRange is updated, but i dont actually do anything with dateRange in this segment (it is used in FormatDataForChart()). So if i were to remove the console.log here the $: would not run when dateRange is updated, is there a way for me to make sure it still runs without having a console.log or similar?
To clarify, the same code segment in react i would do like this:
useEffect(() => {
    formatDataForChart()
        .then(data => chartData = data);
}, [dateRange]);

The only way i can think of "using" dateRange here is by sending it as a parameter to FormatDataForChart(), but that also seems kinda dumb. I am new to Svelte and i just hope there is a better way to deal with this.

There are a few patterns to deal with this.
One is using a sequence expression to list the required dependencies:
$: dateRange, formatDataForChart().then(data => chartData = data);

Another is to explicitly pass parameters, which will be a bit redundant as the variable would already be in scope.
$: formatDataForChart(dateRange).then(data => chartData = data);

What I would usually recommend (if possible), is defining the function reactively, that way any reactive calls will trigger when state within the function is changed:
$: formatDataForChart = () => {
    // [use dateRange here]
};
$: formatDataForChart().then(data => chartData = data);

(In Svelte 5 these workarounds will not be necessary, since the reactivity system can pass function and module boundaries.)

Thanks for the response, i use the third alternative and it works great. However if i understand the code correctly we are essentially redefining the formatDataForChart function every time $: is triggered. If so isn't that quite inefficient use of computing power?

In most cases the impact is quite negligible (the function does not really change either). What usually takes the most amount of time is styles, layout and rendering. Always profile before optimizing anything.
